# How to correct output of special characters that is stored?

Tags: php

I passed the variable with

```
$mytest = "IF('AND(Row(1,NULL,NULL)<Row(2,NULL,NULL),Row(5,NULL,NULL)>0)',1,-1)"
```

But when i echo out the output, it doesnot return me the same value. Instead it removes the `Row(2,NULL,NULL),Row(5,NULL,NULL)` value from the variable.

I have tried using

```
$mytest = urldecode("IF('AND(Row(1,NULL,NULL)<Row(2,NULL,NULL),Row(5,NULL,NULL)>0)',1,-1)")
```

but still its not working. 
It behaves like < as tag >. How can i solve this ?

Comment: do you mean to use `urlencode`?

Comment: @DanielA.White I mean to say when i echo the variable i want the same value in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use:

```
$mytest = htmlspecialchars($mytest);
```

Comment: Thanks i was wondering if someone is able to help me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use htmlspecialchars function .